# USB standard - Speed of a Bit

Tags: usb, speed, time

Ive got a question.
How USB 1.0 negotiate the duration of a bit on output ?
I mean speed of connection ?
Is it const all the time ?

Answer (score 4):

USB 1 supports the following [signal rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Signaling):

> - A **low speed** rate of 1.5 Mbit/s (~183 KB/s) is defined by USB 1.0. It is very similar to "full speed" operation except each bit takes 8 times as long to transmit.
> - The **full speed** rate of 12 Mbit/s (~1.43 MB/s) is the basic USB data rate defined by USB 1.1. All USB hubs support full speed.

The choice of low speed or full speed is indicated by the device when it is connected ([same source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Signaling), emphasis mine):

> The host includes 15 kΩ pull-down resistors on each data line. When
>   no device is connected, this pulls both data lines low into the so-called
>   "single-ended zero" state (SE0 in the USB documentation), and indicates
>   a reset or disconnected connection.
>
> A USB device pulls one of the data lines high with a 1.5 kΩ resistor.
>   This overpowers one of the pull-down resistors in the host and leaves
>   the data lines in an idle state called "J". For USB 1.x, the choice of
>   data line indicates a device's speed support; full-speed devices pull D+
>   high, while **low-speed devices pull D− high**.

The "duration of a bit" signal should be constant, but USB uses bit stuffing -- an extra 0 bit is inserted into the data stream after any appearance of six consecutive 1 bits; thus seven consecutive 1 bits is always an error.  This means that while the duration of a bit is constant, a given byte sequence may take longer to transmit.

See also [NRZI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Return-to-Zero_Inverted#Non-Return-to-Zero_Inverted_.28NRZI.29) and [bit stuffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_stuffing).

Comment: Less than a minute faster than me and more precise! Anyway, +1. Did you worked with USB bus in hardware?

Comment: whitequark provided an excellent article: http://www.obdev.at/developers/articles/00003.html

Comment: @whitequark: yeah, i've done a bit of hardware stuff.  not USB specifically, i'm more familiar with USB from answering questions here.  wikipedia's USB article seems pretty thorough.